# In MS Access VBA determine the next control to have focus

Tags: forms, vba, controls

Understanding the order of operations, is there a way for an OnExit or OnLostFocus script to know what control was clicked to take that focus?

I have a form that has a list box from which you have to select an item for the the rest of the data entered into the form to be saved, so that control has the focus when you open the form. If you click on any other control without selecting an item from the list, an OnExit gives you a warning that you haven't made a selection.

The problem that creates is, should you open the form and then decide you don't want it, you get that message when you close the form (either with the close button on the form or the built-in closer).

I would like to be able to tell the OnExit that either the close button has been clicked or the form itself is closing, so don't show the no entries message.

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: Would [activecontrol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff845144.aspx) work?

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of.

If your form is rather simple(not to many controls.) Move the warning out of the onExit to a sub. Call it from the other controls when they get focus. But not from the Close button.

```
Dim bDidUserSelectSomething As Boolean

'In the list box 
Private sub ListBox1_Click()
    'Do some code here

    'Set the flag that they did something
    bDidUserSelectSomething = True
End sub

'When you enter the other controls, check if they have done what they should have.
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
    If bDidUserSelectSomething = False Then
        'Warning
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider altering your warning check.

Instead of an OnExit() Event of the listbox, add a validation in all other pertinent controls' BeforeUpdate() events. Usually this event is where validation checks are made.

First, build a general function behind the form that calls your warning:

```
Public Function WarningMessage() As Boolean
    If IsNull(Me.Listbox) Then
       Msgbox "Please first select an option in listbox.", vbExclamation, _
               "MISSING LISTBOX SELECTION"
       WarningMessage = True
    Else
       WarningMessage = False
    End If

End Function
```

Then call the function to each control:

```
Private Sub cntr1_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     Cancel = WarningMessage
End Sub

Private Sub cntr2_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
     Cancel = WarningMessage
End Sub

...
```

As you can see from above, if the listbox is null then the message appears and returns True which is passed back to the control's BeforeUpdate() subroutine to cancel the update.

Now, if there are too many controls to make this doable. Consider hiding all relevant controls in Form's OnCurrent() event except the listbox. When listbox is updated, render the other controls visible. Many softwares and web applications run dynamically like this to prevent users from missing important fields.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  If IsNull(Me.listbox) Then
     Me.ctnrl1.Visible = False
     Me.ctnrl2.Visible = False
     Me.ctnrl3.Visible = False
     ...
  Else
     Me.ctnrl1.Visible = True
     Me.ctnrl2.Visible = True
     Me.ctnrl3.Visible = True
     ...
  End if
End Sub 

Private Sub listbox_AfterUpdate()
     Me.ctnrl1.Visible = True
     Me.ctnrl2.Visible = True
     Me.ctnrl3.Visible = True
     ...
End Sub
```